# Change Object Key from a ViewSet DJANGO

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want change a object.key to a another relevant value, like this:

```
class SomeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Some.objects.all()
    serialize_class = SomeSerializer
    ....
    def get_queryset(self):
        some_param = self.request.query_params.get("some_param", None)
        if some_param:
            for some in queryset:
                some.fk_another_key = SomeAnother.objects.get(pk=some.fk_another_key.id)

        return queryset
```

Whats I want is change the `fk__pk` to "fk object". I use rest-framework, and to some cases, not could declares a `"depth"` or `"set object"` in Serializer.

Currently my result json is this

```
{
    ...
    keyX: "",
    keyY: "",
    some_another: 1
    ...
}
```

And I needs some like this

```
{
    ...
    keyX: "",
    keyY: "",
    some_another: {
        ...
        valueX: "",
        valueY: ""
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You've got to change the serializer to do that. See the documentation and nested serializers in particular.

Comment: In Serializer I can have "parameters" and with this changes the "serializer"?

Comment: See here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do that is to modify your serializer so that the some_another foreign key is serialized using the corresponding "SomeAnother" serializer

```
class SomeAnotherSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = SomeAnother
       fields = ('pk', 'valueX', 'valueY')


class SomeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    some_another = SomeAnotherSerializer()

    class Meta:
       model = Some
       fields = ('pk', 'keyX', 'keyY', 'some_another ')
```